# Getting error in application class when try to run flutter application on Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

When I was trying to run my application, getting the error ' Class 'Application' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun reg
isterWith(p0: PluginRegistry): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback'. This app worked before I update flutter version to 3.0.1. How to solve this issue?.

#### Log

```
Class 'Application' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member
public abstract fun registerWith(p0: PluginRegistry): Unit
defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback

\Application.kt: (22, 5): 'registerWith' overrides nothing

\MainActivity.kt: (13, 1): Class 'MainActivity' is not abstract and does not
implement abstract member public abstract fun registerWith(p0: PluginRegistry): Unit 
defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback

\MainActivity.kt: (22, 5): 'registerWith' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Comment: Post your error log, this error of `PluginRegistrantCallback` is one of the worst errors of Flutter as there's no exact solution for this, it's all hit and miss and sadly, it's common.

Comment: This is all i got as error log from my console